# Dynamically assign variable from HTML to AS3 variable

Tags: javascript, flash, actionscript-3, actionscript

I have an HTML button that I need to dynamically assign to an AS3 variable when clicked (in order to load an .mp3).  I am using externalInterface.call to collect javascript variables - I am just unsure how to change these dynamically when a button is clicked.

Can anybody help me learn with some sample code?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [ExternalInterface.addCallback](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/external/ExternalInterface.html#addCallback%28%29) to add a method to your *.swf that can be called from javascript code.

```
ExternalInterface.addCallback("testMethod", function(message:String) { trace(message) });
```

And in javascript:

```
document.getElementById('swf').testMethod('Hello!');
```

Answer (score 0):

`ExternalInterface` is one way, and @Andrey M has already provided some good tips on this approach.

However, if you're just passing values from HTML -> AS, consider using [FlashVars](http://kb2.adobe.com/cps/164/tn_16417.html), which are a more appropriate approach.